# How to simplify unit testing with higher order functions?

Tags: unit-testing, functions, higher-order-functions

- this is *not* a question on how to write unit tests
- this is *not* a question on what to test
- this is a question on reducing the typing needed overall for a personal testing framework

I know you can send function pointers as arguments to functions in C.

Is there a c++98 version?  Or, since c++ can work backwards, should I just use the C function pointer method?

I am trying to write a function that tests functions for me.  I don't want to write a long list of:

```
try {
  func1()
  out << fail
} except e {
  out << pass
}

if (func2(arg2) == expected_val) {
  out << pass
else
  out << fail

try/catch...
try/catch...
if/else...
try/catch...
...etc
```

but maybe instead:

```
test_this(func1, passes_on_exception)
test_this(func2, ! passes_on_exception, expected_val2, arg2)
test_this(func3, passes_on_exception)
test_this(func4...
test_this(func5...
...etc

void test_this(func_name, pass_on_exception, expected_value, arg1, ..., argn) {
  if pass_on_exception {
      try {
          func_name(arg1)
          out << fail
      } catch e {
          out << pass
      }
  } else {
      if func_name == expected_value {
          out << pass
      } else {
          out << fail
      }
  }
}
```

Virtual functions seems out of the question since, if I recall correctly, the function names have to be overridden/hardcoded; as in, I would need to create a new class to inherit and override the functions, in which case, I would redeclare the function, and also retype all of those try/catch... the chain of try/catch/if/else seems better.

If there was a way to pass function names to other functions, I think I can figure it out from there.  Unless the above is actually impossible in C++, then please stop me before I start, and I'll just bear with that long list of try/catch/if/else unit testing method.  So, main question: is there a way to do the above?  If not, alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use function pointers in C++, more generally you can use std::tr1::function for any sort of callable thing (function, method or lambda)
e.g.

```
// Use <functional> for C++11
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::tr1;

void first(function<void()> f)
{
  f();
}

void second()
{
  cout << "second\n";
}

int main()
{
  first(second);
}
```

Comment: That's available in c++98?  Ahaha, should have tried it first; but the c++ site said c++11 only.

Comment: strictly 98, no, but if you have tr1 available then you can get it via tr1, or IIRC boost also provides a function wrapper

Comment: So, given I only have 98, function pointers are the only option for me, huh?

Comment: It depends a C++98 compiler may very well have std::tr1 available as its just a library extension, if you have to use strictly C++98 std libraries only then yes use function pointers (or I guess you could write your own function template if you are brave)